# Angular referencing model and display the data

Tags: angular

I have added two models. These models are referenced each other and I want to get data from comment.When i am using the following html code,everything is fine but the code is not working: @{{comment.user?.name}}. Please check out the following codes and let me know if you have any guidelines ?     Thanks

```
**These two Models i am using in the source code: User and Comment**

import { Video } from './Videos';

export class User{


constructor(
   public id?:number,
  public name?:string,
    public type?: string,
    public video?: Video,
    public comment?: Comment){}
}



import { User } from './user';
import { Video } from './Videos';

export class Comment{


    constructor(
        id:number,
        userId: number,
        videoId:number,
        date:Date,
        body:string,
       user?:User[],
       video?:Video[] ){ }
}


**It is a component Ts source code :**


export class CommentslistComponent implements OnInit {


public comments:Comment[]=[];
  constructor(private videoService:VideoService)  { }

  ngOnInit() {

  this.videoService.getComments()
  .then((response) => {response.json()
  .then((res:Comment[])=>{
    this.comments=res;
    console.log(res);
    });
  })
  }


**HTML file where i want to display the data**

<li class="media" *ngFor="let comment of comments">
                            <a href="#" class="pull-left">
                                <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle">
                            </a>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <span class="text-muted pull-right">
                                    <small class="text-muted">{{comment.date}}</small>
                                </span>
                                <strong class="text-success" >   @{{comment.user?.name}}</strong>
                                <p>
                                   {{comment.body}}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

Looking forward to your response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe on observable/promise instead of second then.
The user is array so you have to iterate over the user array

Comment: Everything is fine but the code is not working: @{{comment.user?.name}}.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Angular's [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http#httpclient) to handle HTTP requests on your service.ts.

On your component.ts, you will need to use the `subscribe()` method to return the observables, such that the values can be used within your component.

If you `console.log(res)`, you can check if the values are actually returned (and not `undefined`)

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.videoService.getComments().subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    this.comments = res;
    // do the rest
  });
}
```

Comment: It returns the actual values. I used the fetch api :https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder#how-to

Comment: @SHO yes, but I recommend you to handle them as an observable instead of promise. Also, `res` is an array of objects, right?

Comment: Yes, but trying to fix this way.

Answer (score 0):

In class Comment you have user?:User[] which is array of User type. That's why `{{comment.user?.name}}`
not working.It will accessible like `{{comment.user[0]?.name}}`. Hope you will understand my point. Thus in HTML you can use *ngFor for comment.user like follows :

```
<li class="media" *ngFor="let comment of comments">
    <a href="#" class="pull-left">
        <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
        <span class="text-muted pull-right">
            <small class="text-muted">{{comment.date}}</small>
        </span>
        <strong class="text-success" *ngFor="let item of comments.user"> 
            {{item?.name}}
        </strong>
        <p>
            {{comment.body}}
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Hope this will help